# ActiveMQ stomp transport allows publishing messages even if credentials are wrong

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

I've been trying ActiveMQ `5.15.8` using the Stomp transport from Python. I have a producer and a consumer. So far the consumer is receiving the messages as expected, the problem is that even if I send wrong credentials with the `CONNECT` command it will always accept the connection without sending an `ERROR` frame (based on ActiveMQ [docs](http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html)).

I tried with [stomp.py](https://pypi.org/project/stomp.py/) library but also tried by sending the data directly via a TCP socket connection and got the same behavior.

Is it possible that I am missing some configuration? I am using default settings on ActiveMQ, I can access to the web console via `admin/admin`.

This the `activemq.xml` file that I have:

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}" schedulerSupport="true">
        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>
        <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>

        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?needClientAuth=true&amp;maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>
    </broker>
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>
</beans>
```

I really appreciate if you can give some help. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the broker configuration.

Comment: @JustinBertram thanks, I added the `activemq.xml` settings file

Comment: You need to configure authorization as well in the broker config. See example: http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/activemq/trunk/activemq-unit-tests/src/test/resources/org/apache/activemq/security/jaas-broker.xml

Comment: Thank you @PetterNordlander, I started using the JAAS plugin. Although all authentication validations are failing it is a good starting point to continue investigating.